# how to pad a string in jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Say I'm incrementing an integer like this

```
 {% capture page %}{{ page | plus: '1' }}{% endcapture %}
```

How could I pad it like this?

```
 {% capture paddedPage %}{{ page | pad '0', 4 }}{% endcapture %}
```

where 4 is number of padding places, and '0' is the padding string? The end result would look like this: `0001` where the value of page is 1. How might I do this inline or in a filter?

I guess it could be *represented* like sprintf( '%d4', page ) but obviously this syntax does not work with liquid/jekyll.

I'm growing really disappointed in jekyll/liquid syntax (does not even have native modulus!) That aside, how might I pad a string with leading characters?

Comment: You could try Middleman, it uses ERB instead of Liquid http://staticgen.com/middleman

Comment: well if i was going to switch tech, i'd switch to something node.js based that used js syntax like http://wintersmith.io/.

Comment: Im just saying it might be easier, ERB is part of ruby so that is one less dependency

Comment: hah, yeah Liquid is a bizarre templating choice. I guess since it sprang out of ecommerce, they wanted "safety" over syntactic sugar.

Comment: best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453646/1536309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Liquid you can do :

```
{% assign pad     = 4 %}
{% assign padStr  = '0' %}
{% assign numbers = "1|12|123|1234" | split: "|" %}
{% for number in numbers %}
  {% assign strLength = number | size %}
  {% assign padLength = pad | minus: strLength %}
  {% if padLength > 0 %}
    {% assign padded = number %}
    {% for position in (1..padLength) %}
      {% assign padded = padded | prepend: padStr %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>{{ number}} padded to {{ padded }}</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>{{ number}} no padding needed</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note : Liquid modulus filter is `{{ 12 | modulo: 5 }}`

Answer (score 22):

Use liquid filter [prepend](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#prepend) and [slice](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#slice), like this:

```
{{ page | prepend: '0000' | slice: -4, 4 }}
```